# Ajax file upload working only at Opera

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-upload

I try to upload photo with Ajax, have written code that has worked without Problems in Opera (My Standard Browser). Now i have tested it in other browsers, they all shooting with errors back. My PHP script starts with

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    //todo
} else {
    exit();
}
```

So i tried to put `var_dump($_FILES); die();` at the start to see whats wrong.
They all give this back `array(0) {}`. I have tested it on FireFox, Chrome, Safari (All latest version), IE9 on win7 and latest Firefox on Debian. The biggest problem, i don't understand why it don't working, because in developer tools and all browsers above, i can see the file with right name in right position.

Here is my JS to upload:

```
var photo_input1 = document.createElement('input');

photo_input1.setAttribute('type','file');
photo_input1.setAttribute('class','photo_input');
photo_input1.setAttribute('id','photo1');
photo_input1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    upload_photo(this.id,this.files[0])
});

var upload_photo = function(filename,file) {
    var data_arr = Array();
    data_arr['callback_name'] = 'upload_photo';
    upload_file(filename,file,'add_photo.php',data_arr);
}

var upload_file = function(filename,file,url,data_arr) {
    var datapack = null;
    var ajaxanswer = function() {
        try {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
                if (ajax.status == 200) {
                    //todo
                } else {
                    alert('Problems:' + "\n" + ajax.statusText);
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {
        }
    }

    try {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            var ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                var ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if(ajax) {
        if(typeof url != 'undefined') {
            datapack = new FormData;
            datapack.append(filename,file);
            if(typeof data_arr != 'undefined') {
                for(key in data_arr) {
                    datapack.append(key, data_arr[key]);
                }
            }
            ajax.open('POST',url, true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
            ajax.onreadystatechange = ajaxanswer;
            ajax.send(datapack);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: on browser console is there an error?

Comment: no errors, empty response, because of empty $_FILES

Comment: Search stackoverflow for uploading files with Ajax.

Comment: I have read about 20 discussions and no where find my situation with a answer thats help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to upload files using ajax. The normal way to do is to use a iframe internal and submit the form using the iframe. You can read about one of the way [here](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html).

Also you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload#answer-2320097).

> With XHR2, File upload through AJAX is supported. E.g. through [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object, but unfortunately it is not supported by all/old browsers

Answer (score 0):

FormData only works in Opera v12 and up as other relatively new browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData

You can try this for Ajax-like file uploading : https://github.com/valums/file-uploader. As Arun P Johny mentioned, there is no uploading with Ajax, but you can use some workarounds, like hidden iframe in this case.